# Shape.Rotation property behavior

Tags: excel, vba

```
With sketch
    .ScaleHeight 16, msoFalse
    .ScaleWidth 16, msoFalse
    .Fill.Visible = False
    .Line.Weight = 1
    .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    .Left = XCoordinate
    .Top = YCoordinate
    .Rotation = AngleDeg
End With
```

This is a code i am writing. I have X and Y coordinate calculated using a formula that changes during every iteration of for loop.

My question is does this shape then go to the given X and Y before rotating itself? Plus, **what is the axis of rotation it uses when it rotates by this angle value** stored in variable AngleDeg?

I am concerned about this because if this rotates about it's left top corner, then it is a problem for me because i need it to rotate about axis passing through it's center point.  Same is the reason for why i have my scalewidth and scaleheight properties before this Left and Top properties.

I found that it was using correct X and Y of my center of the sketch (calculated considering origin of the sketch is left top corner), but then it was getting disturbed when it was scaling the sketch which was then moving/messing up the co-ordinates of the center of the sketch.

Please guide.

Comment: You could just give it a try on a sample workbook and check the results when you step through your code =)

Comment: i did and it does rotate about left top corner of the sketch. it really complicates my X and Y coordinate. is there a way to rotate about center of the sketch? like can we define the rotation center for .rotation property?

Comment: I'm afraid VBA Excel does not have a property able to (directly) change the shape rotation center. It can be done in a little more complicated way making some calculations. You can be inspired from [this](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/core/index.php?attachment/1128183-00-rotate-out-center-xls/) (old) .xls file and its VBA code. You can play with 'Pt_2 height from bottom rectangle', see what is happening and adjust the code to keep the rotation center in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

The next procedure is able to rotate a shape, according to its center coordinates. Of course, when you test it (unchanged), on the active worksheet you must have a shape named 'sketch':

```
Sub testRotFunction()
  Dim sketch As Shape
  Set sketch = ActiveSheet.Shapes("sketch")
  centerRotation sketch, 0
End Sub

Sub centerRotation(sR As Shape, rotAngle As Double)
    Dim rad As Double, x As Double, y As Double
    Dim x1 As Double, x2 As Double

    x = sR.Top: y = sR.Left
    x1 = (sR.Width / 2) * -1
    x2 = sR.Height
    rad = rotAngle * Atn(1) / 45

    With sR
        .Top = x + (.Height - .Width / 2 - x1 - x2) * (1 - Cos(rad)) / 2
        .Left = y + (.Height - .Width / 2 - x1 - x2) * Sin(rad) / 2
        .Rotation = rotAngle
    End With
End Sub
```